# Adding to ICollection of type entity issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entities, icollection

Can some one help Not sure what I am doping wrong:

in my controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult SaveRecommendedUserDetails(RecommendAFriendViewModel model)
 {
    //List<Entities.Group.Group> entityGroups = new List<Entities.Group.Group>();

        foreach (var group in model.Groups)
        {
          Entities.Group.Group entityGroup = new Entities.Group.Group();
          entityGroup.GroupId = group.GroupId;
          //entityGroups.Add(entityGroup);
          recommendedUser.Groups.Add(entityGroup); //groups in recommendeduser is already of type ICollection.
        }
 }
```

RecommendAFriendViewModel model Groups property:

```
 public IEnumerable<DataModels.Group.GroupDataModel> Groups { get; set; }
```

RecommendedUser entity Groups property:

```
  public virtual ICollection<Group.Group> Groups { get; set; }
```

on the two red lines i get: cannot convert from 'int' to 'Zinc.Entities.Group.Group'
and: The best overloaded method match for system.Collections.Generic.List.Add(Zinc.Entities.Group.Group)' has some invalid arguments

can some on show me what I am doing wrong please?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You never initialized the `entityGroups` variable. Before using a variable you should make sure that it is assigned. Also the scope of your `entityGroup` could be moved to the `foreach` loop:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveRecommendedUserDetails(RecommendAFriendViewModel model)
{
    var entityGroups = new List<Entities.Group.Group>();
    foreach (var group in model.Groups)
    {
        if (!recommendedUser.Groups.Any(x => x.GroupId == group.GroupId))
        {
            var entityGroup = new Entities.Group.Group();
            entityGroup.GroupId = group.GroupId;
            entityGroups.Add(entityGroup.GroupId);
        }
    }
    recommendedUser.Groups.Add(entityGroups);
}
```

Comment: thanks i moved the one line into the foreach and changed the ICollection to List but still get red line on recommendedUser.Groups.Add(entityGroups); with same "error" as the other red line even after i moved the new Entities.Group.Group(); to into the foreach

Comment: What's `recommendedUser`? I cannot see you declaring this variable anywhere.

Comment: What compile error message are you getting when you tried using my code?

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Zinc.Entities.Group.Group>.Add(Zinc.Entities.Group.Group)' has some invalid arguments cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List<Zinc.Entities.Group.Group>' to 'Zinc.Entities.Group.Group'

Comment: Where did you see `ICollection` in my answer? Please read my answer more carefully once again.

Answer (score 0):

You're not instantiating a new `Entities.Group.Group` object with each iteration of your `foreach` loop.  All you're doing is overwriting the last `entityGroup.GroupId` propery set, then attempting to add the same entity object to the collection when it's already in there from a previous iteration.

Moving your entityGroup variable declaration inside the `if` statement should solve you're problem.

```
if (!recommendedUser.Groups.Any(x => x.GroupId == group.GroupId))
{
  Entities.Group.Group entityGroup = new Entities.Group.Group(); // here
  entityGroup.GroupId = group.GroupId;
  entityGroups.Add(entityGroup); //get red line here
}
```

Comment: thanks thought that much, but I still get red line on the .add line stating best overload method match..has some invalid arguments

Comment: oh, duh, i just noticed you're attempting to add a GroupId to a colleciton of Group objects.  you just want to add the entityGroup object - i updated my example